# Превью картинки

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Здравствуйте!
Есть `RecyclerView`, который отображает несколько картинок. Хочется сделать чтобы по нажатию на одну из них, открывалось превью картинки, как будто мы в галлерее смотрим. Подобный пример есть в Telegram'e. Подскажите в какую сторону копать? 
Можно ли задачу решить стандартными способами(может `Intent`, какой). Или придется делать самому экран который будет открываться и делать все что мне надо?

Answer (score 1):

В этом вопросе тоже самое обсуждается , чтобы отображать через стандартный интент нужно картинку сохранять на SD карту:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831562/android-show-image-in-default-gallery-viewer

А тут например реализация для просмотра картинки на своем экране:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out